# How can I fix these multiple problems that deal with slope?

Tags: java

I want to make a little piece of code that makes and ellipse go toward another point.

The principle is simple enough:

```
int ellipseX = 30;
int ellipseY = 30;
int ellipse1X = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
int ellipse1Y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
//m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
double slopex = ellipse1X/ellipseX;
double slopey = ellipse1Y/ellipseY;
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.fillOval(ellipseX, ellipseY, 4, 4);
    ellipseX+=slopex;
    ellipseY+=slopey;
    repaint();
}
```

Now there are a couple of problems with that-

- double + int = double making it unable to be a possible "x" or "y" for the ellipse.
- Slope doesn't update so that it only goes in that direction and stays that way.

And a whole bunch of problems besides. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post complete code, so that I can run in IDE to replicate your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little trick in dividing two integers when you expect a double as the return type. You need to explicitly cast the numbers to double before performing the division. here is a quick fix to that I also changed the data types for ellipseX and ellipseY to double:

```
double ellipseX = 30;
double ellipseY = 30;
int ellipse1X = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
int ellipse1Y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
//m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
double slopex = (double)ellipse1X/ellipseX;
double slopey = (double)ellipse1Y/ellipseY;
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.fillOval((int)ellipseX, (int)ellipseY, 4, 4);
    ellipseX+=slopex;
    ellipseY+=slopey;
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I can see in the code is that you are storing the result of dividing 2 integer variables into a double. If you check, the double will contain a whole number value. Instead, you should do something along the lines of,

```
double myDouble = (numerator * 1.0) / denominator;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the slope to follow your mouse pointer then you incorporate inside the loop - I dont know what slope will give you and I'm  not sure the equations are right - just answering your this question - also see for int+double

```
int ellipseX = 30;
int ellipseY = 30;
int ellipse1X = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
int ellipse1Y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
  double slopex = ellipse1X/ellipseX;
  double slopey = ellipse1Y/ellipseY;
while(true) {
  ellipse1X = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
  ellipse1Y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
  slopex = ellipse1X/ellipseX;
  slopey = ellipse1Y/ellipseY;
  ellipseX=(int)Math.rint(ellipseX+slopex);
  ellipseY=(int)Math.rint(ellipseY+slopey);
  repaint()
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.fillOval(ellipseX, ellipseY, 4, 4);
}
```

repaint should not be generally called within paint()

Comment: What I want is an ellipse that constantly goes toward my mouse, not a "painting tool"

Comment: yes but that ellipse should be within a window (JPanel JFrame etc) while the mouse can be anywhere - maybe you want a window that covers the whole screen

Comment: Yes, do that and figure out all the stuff up there and I'll accept this.